# Pattern for saving, updating and retrieving objects in Java

Tags: java, design-patterns

Whilst designing Java applications, I have come across a common pattern where I am writing an application that receives orders from a user and saves them in storage. When an order is stored, it can also be retrieved via its ID, and also some action done to it, e.g. have its cancelled flag set to true.

The common issue I have is how to handle the, say cancel, request. Say I have an OrderService, that has an OrderRepository that handles the storage of Orders (maybe the repo deals with Hibernate but that doesn't matter).

```
public OrderRepo {
    public void addOrder(Order order);
    public Order find(Integer orderID);
    public void cancel(Integer orderID);
}
```

When implementing cancel(), is it best to allow the client to first call find(id) to locate the order to be cancelled, or is it best to add logic to the cancel() method to do this, as follows:

```
List<Order> orders = new ArrayList<>();

public Order find(Integer orderID) throws OrderNotFoundException {
    Order order = orders.stream().filter(o->o.getId()==orderID) etc;
    if(order == null) {
        throw OrderNotFoundException();
    }
    return order;
}

public void cancel(Integer orderID) throws OrderNotFoundException {
    Order order = find(orderID);
    order.cancel();
}
```

Or should I add logic to the OrderService, as follows:

```
public void cancelOrder(Integer orderID) {
    try{
        Order order = repo.find(orderID);
        if(order!=null) {
            order.cancel();
        }
    } catch(OrderNotFoundException e) {
        log error()
    }
}
```

And leave the repo simpler:

```
public Order find(Integer orderID)  {
    return orders.stream().filter(o->o.getId()==orderID) etc;
}

public void cancel(Integer orderID)  {
    Order order = find(orderID);
    order.cancel();
}
```

The question is, who's responsibility is it to handle orders not found? Are exceptions the best way or should I be using Optional. If I use optional, the user doesn't know the order doesn't exist, just that it wasn't returned.

As I said, this seems to be a common theme I'm running into and I widened if there's a design pattern I should be following.

Comment: Why else could the order be not returned from the repository? In this case exceptions are fine, as there is no useful way for a client to obtain an order ID without creating one, and this means, they are unable to obtain an ID of an absent order.

Comment: Why does addOrder not return an ID?